# Chunker/shallow parser for spoken language

Tags: nlp, preprocessing, parsing, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to extract NPs from transcribed spoken text, such as

> um it's the bl- it's the blue one in the right no left hand corner

which contains e.g. fillers (e.g. *um*) and disfluencies (e.g. *bl-*, *right no left hand corner*) that are not commonly seen in written text. Ideally, I'd like to get something like the three sequences *it*, *the blue one* and *the left hand corner* (or at the very least *the right no left hand corner*).

I'm currently using Stanford CoreNLP's pre-trained [shift-reduce parser](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/srparser.shtml) with a [beam size of 4](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/srparser.shtml#beam) (`englishSR.beam.ser.gz`) and bidirectional [dependency network POS tagging](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml) (`english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger`) after filtering out fillers and duplicated tokens (e.g. *uh it's it's that one* → *it's that one*). This performs okay but seems to fail a lot more than I'd expect; **Are there no chunkers or (shallow) parsers widely available which are tailored specifically to spoken English as opposed to written English?** The language the chunker/parser is written in is irrelevant (i.e. it needn't have a Java API). I've also tried using Stanford CoreNLP's caseless models, which actually seem to perform a bit worse (however, I haven't done any rigorous comparisons).

Comment: Would the downvoter not like to make a useful comment?